# Capture Method object as parameter in the advice AspectJ

Tags: java, aspectj

I need to execute some checks before the execution of a method, but I need to get this method as an object by reflection and them pass it to another object as a callback. For example:

I have a view controller and I need to make an access control on some methods with an specific annotation. This method makes a navigation to an View that need a control access by password previously configurated.

```java
    @AccessControl(accessID = "bookKeysViewId")
    private void navigateToBookKeys() {
        navigateTo(ControllerPasswordBookKey.class);
    }
```

Before the execution of the method I need check de access. For example:

```java
pointcut makeAccessControl() : execution(@AccessControl * *(..));

before() : makeAccessControl(){
    Method method =  // any way to get the intercepted method
    String idAccess = // get de access id from method annotation
    EnumTypeAccess typeAccess = ManagerAccess.checkAccess(idAccess);
    switch (typeAccess ){
            case NEEDED: openPasswordDialog();break; // wrong password ?  throw an exception and interrupt the method execution.
            case NEED_CONFIG: // create configuration view, pass "method" as callback and navigate to it
        }


}
```

Comment: An aspect without the application code it should intercept is not helpful. Only if you show both someone can help you. What does the code look like? Why do you think you need reflection and a `Method` object just to print its name? Please learn what an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is, then edit your question in order to create one. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks for your edit. I just noticed by chance. Please note that I am not notified of edits, next time please write a quick comment.

Comment: Thanks a lot to you, about the comment I will do

Comment: How can I mark your answer as the right one ?

Comment: To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in. Maybe you want to read some FAQ in order to find out how this site works, e.g. [how to accept an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/309898).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let us take a look at this little [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve):

**Marker annotation:**

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

import static java.lang.annotation.ElementType.METHOD;
import static java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Target(METHOD)
public @interface AccessControl {
  String accessID();
}
```

**Driver application:**

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

public class Application {
  public void doSomething() {
    navigateToBookKeys();
  }

  @AccessControl(accessID = "bookKeysViewId")
  private void navigateToBookKeys() {}

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Application().doSomething();
  }
}
```

**Aspect:**

You can bind your method annotation to an advice parameter via `@annotation(accessControl)` and declaring that parameter and its type in the pointcut (or directly in the advice for inline pointcuts).

The `Method` object you want (for whatever reason) you can get via `((MethodSignature) thisJoinPoint.getSignature()).getMethod()`.

```java
package de.scrum_master.aspect;

import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import org.aspectj.lang.reflect.MethodSignature;
import de.scrum_master.app.AccessControl;

public aspect AccessControlAspect {
  pointcut makeAccessControl(AccessControl accessControl) :
    @annotation(accessControl) &&
    execution(* *(..));

  before(AccessControl accessControl) : makeAccessControl(accessControl) {
    Method method = ((MethodSignature) thisJoinPoint.getSignature()).getMethod();
    String accessID = accessControl.accessID();
    System.out.println(thisJoinPoint);
    System.out.println("  method   = " + method);
    System.out.println("  accessID = " + accessID);
  }

}
```

**Console log:**

```
execution(void de.scrum_master.app.Application.navigateToBookKeys())
  method   = private void de.scrum_master.app.Application.navigateToBookKeys()
  accessID = bookKeysViewId
```